# Disable panel synchronization (remove button)

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to remove the option to disable panel synchronization. Any chance there is a flag for this that I somehow overlooked?

I am able to remove it if I update the navtreedata.js file, but then when I rebuild it comes back. I have added navtree.js to the HTML_EXTRA_FILES, but maybe it needs to be somewhere else as well?

Panel synchronization button is circled in this image.

[image: Panel synchronization button is circled in this image.]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no flag for this, it looks like it is deep down in the the doxygen generated navtree.js (line like `n.html('<img src="'+relpath+'sync_off.png" title="'+SYNCOFFMSG+'"/>');``). You could modify this file and copy it to the html directory (entirely on your  own risk)

Comment: Ok - I'll test it out and see what happens. Thanks for doing the digging!